# How to use Linq-to-SQL without having to generate all the classes?

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

I have never used Linq-to-Sql before in an application but I used LinqPad to develop a query and just wanted to paste it into into my code.

It's not so simple. I guessed that I need a `DataContext` to handle the connection but I still get errors because the view names aren't recognised.

Do I *have* to use the designer and *create all* the View/Table- classes? Is there a more simple way?

This is the query. Don't need any updates - just this one query....

```
var q = from user in V020
    join userapp in V010 on user.SPP_USER_ID equals userapp.SPP_USER_ID
    join app in V030 on userapp.SPP_AW_ID equals app.SPP_AW_ID
    join tx in V040 on app.SPP_AW_ID equals tx.SPP_AW_ID
    join appber in V070 on app.SPP_AW_ID equals appber.SPP_AW_ID
    join ber in V050 on appber.SPP_AW_BEREICH_ID equals ber.SPP_AW_BEREICH_ID 

    where app.SPP_AW_AKTIV && user.SPP_USER_ID == "userid" && tx.SPP_AW_SPR == "de" && ber.SPP_AW_SPR == "de"

    orderby ber.SPP_BER_SORTNB

    select new {
        AppName = app.SPP_AW_KURZBEZ, Url = tx.SPP_AW_URL, Label = tx.SPP_AW_NAME, Description = tx.SPP_AW_BESCHR,
        Bereich = ber.SPP_AW_BERNAME,
        Owner = app.SPP_AW_VERANTW, Remote = app.SPP_AW_REMOTE
    }

    ;
```

Comment: Have a look at [SQLMetal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: How have you got these objects in LinqPad?

Comment: @DavidG - in LinqPad I just connect to the database and write the query. Everything else is done transparently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Add dbml file]

1. Create a dbml file, as above
2. Open the 'server explorer'
3. Connect to your database
4. Drag the tables you wish to use from your database connection onto the designer
5. Party time

Comment: Thanks but my question is not 'How to do it' but rather 'Is it necessary'. Do I really have to create all the classes. LinqPad perhaps is doing all that under the covers - no idea

Comment: @paul You have to do it. Without it, it isn't possible.

Comment: @paul Yes LinqPad is generating all the classes for you.

Answer (score 0):

In EF I have used context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand to run a stored procedure without the need to use domain modal designer (and hence generating the tables). I am sure you can do something similar in Linq to SQL. However this will not support the linq query you have. You need to move all the logic in stored procedure.

SiteManagedRepairDetails Model properties:

```
 public long RepairID { get; set; }
 public int RepairLineID { get; set; }
```

DAL method:

```
public static int UpsertData(SiteManagedRepairDetails obj)
        {

            XYZ.DBContexts.VoidsDBContext context = new XYZ.DBContexts.VoidsDBContext();
            var results = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("p_XYZDetailsUpsert @RepairID, @RepairLineID"
                , new SqlParameter("@RepairID", obj.RepairID)
                , new SqlParameter("@RepairLineID", obj.RepairLineID)
            );
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Is this really linq-to-SQL ... ?